# How to put the dragged image behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, bringtofront

I want to use the Drag & Drop system to give the user the feeling he puts the item in a box. My xaml looks like :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock CanDrag="True"/>
    </Grid>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Image Stource="box.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But the item dragged is always on the top, though the TextBlock has been defined before the image. Is it possible to send it to the back, or to bring my image to the front ?

Comment: You'll need to define an OnDrop event handler and in the handler specify the ZIndex of the dropped object.

Comment: use a canvas instead, then you can define the zindex property for each element, either statically or dynamically

Comment: I think you can set the ZIndex even when it's not a canvas.

Comment: The TextBlock is under the image, but not the dragged object. I modified the code that way:
     <Canvas>
            <TextBlock Text="Coucou" CanDrag="True" Canvas.ZIndex="100"/>
            <Image Source="box.png" Canvas.ZIndex="500" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"/>
     </Canvas>

Comment: The TextBlock is behind the image. The problem is to send the object dragged to the back.